# Where is the Putrid Grove?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was already there once during the main quest, but I can't find the place again. I read later that there is a merchant there selling really good saddlebags, and I'd like to visit that merchant. But Novigrad is just so big, and I didn't memorize the location of Putrid Grove.

Where exactly in Novigrad is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter the city from glory gate take the left on the main road and circle around the "block". Before the intersection you should see a door (as in the picture) on the right, knock and you're in "putrid grove"!

Below image of the Door, and an image of the map facing the door.

[image: Front Door]
[image: Map]

Answer (score -3):

Here you go, no idea if you've found it in the meantime.

Comment: share some explanation because if the video goes down the answer will be useless